Either the \setlength command or the printlen package is not working
The following MWE
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{printlen}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{12pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\begin{document}
    \verb!abovedisplayskip! in points (\verb!pt!):\the\abovedisplayskip
\end{document}

produces this result:

So is the setlength command not working, is the printlen package not working, or is my understanding of latex not working?

Between both is the command \begin{document} which does lots of things. Why do you assume that it leaves the length untouched?

Well I was just thinking programmatically, as in, I modified the variable \abovedisplayskip, then later asked what its value is and it wasn't what I set it to. I didn't realize \begin{document} did much. But my real problem is that I'm trying to remove glue from equation spacing because Latex keeps screwing up my vertical space if the page is full. I've already tried \raggedbottom but it didn't do anything.

you could remove the printlen package from your example. you aren't using it and it makes no difference whatsoever.

Oh I thought that's what allowed you to print that stuff in your document. I just copied that from another post because I'm trying to remove glue from equation spacing.

@JasonD. I can't tell you what printlen is for without looking it up as I've never heard of it before, but you certainly don't need it to print the values of dimensions, lengths, skips etc. you don't need latex for that either because you're just using the underlying tex method here: \the. \the\parskip, \the\textheight, \the\baselineskip, \the\pagetotal etc.

If you really want to do this --- and I don't recommend it unless you need grid typesetting (e.g. for publishing a book on thinnish paper), you must do it later to ensure non-interference by the kernel and/or class.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\AddToHook{begindocument}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{12pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}%
}
\begin{document}
\verb!abovedisplayskip! in points (\verb!pt!): \the\abovedisplayskip
\end{document}

gives the target result.
Do note that this makes it more difficult for LaTeX to find good page breaks. The symptoms you describe would probably be better addressed in other ways. That is, this strikes me as likely an 'XY' problem and I'm only telling you how to find 'X'.

That's exactly correct :). Anyways I understand now, thanks to you and Ulrike, that \begin{document} does a lot of stuff behind the scenes. All I'm doing is making a test, but Latex crowds everything into one page which screws up my delicately placed hlines. So I think you're right. I need to approach this differently (and/or) ask the real question that I'm trying to solve.

@JasonD. \begin{document} has become so crowded we now have methods of ordering the stuff it does because all kinds of packages also add code there. that's not relevant here, but real documents rarely have such sparse preambles. in many cases, values will be changed multiple times at \begin{document} as different chunks of code vie for supremacy ;).
